# How to enable SSL communication between two Apache Tomcat servers

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl, client-server, ssl-certificate

I have two computer systems each having an apache server. One machine is a client machine and the other is a server machine. I want both the client request and the server response to be encrypted thus making the data transfer safe.

Could someone please give pointers/steps on how I could make progress in this front.
The communication doesn't involve any GUI components meaning the communication is purely a backend one.

Both the client and the server are coded in java. I am using Axis2 and jaxws for the communication.

Currently I am able to send the client request and receive the server response without SSL enabled. Now If I enable SSL does it mean that I should also modify the existing code according to the SSL or the current working code still holds good.

Comment: What kind of client is running on your client machine? Is it a PHP script running within the first server, is the first server a reverse proxy? You've tagged this with (Apache) Tomcat. Is one of the machines using Apache Httpd too? Which one?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Both the client and the server is coded in java.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here. Since you mention SSL...
On each server generate an asymmetric key-pair (RSA 2048 is a safe choice). Then create a self signed certificate on each server. Then copy each certificate to the other machine and mark it as trusted by the Java environment that apache is using and that NONE OTHER are trusted. Configure SSL/TLS on each of the apaches to use a good symmetric cypher (3DES is a safe choice, but there are other newer ciphers if you want leading edge). Next ensure that all access between Tomcat servers is via https URLs and you should be in decent shape.

An alternative is to use IPSEC to establish a static tunnel between the two servers using certificates or other trust bases.

Comment: Currently I am able to send the client request and receive the server response without SSL enabled. Now If I enable SSL does it mean that I should also modify the existing code according to the SSL or the current working code still holds good.

Comment: Aside from changing the URLs to be https rather than http you don't need code changes just apache config changes.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly simple option is to use [`stunnel`](http://www.stunnel.org/index.html), which is available via the standard package-manager on most *NIX systems. You configure an stunnel as a client (and server if you with) on one server and then another as the server (and client if you wish) and then configure your Tomcat instance(s) to connect to localhost:XYZ where XYZ is the port where stunnel is listening.

The nice part about using `stunnel` is that you can use it to tunnel any protocol: it is neither a Tomcat-specific nor a Java-specific technique, so you can use it for other applications in the same environment if you want.

Comment: That's a bit convoluted, considering that Java (and Tomcat) support HTTPS out of the box.

Comment: The OP asked about Tomcat -> Tomcat communication, which is not something supported out-of-the box, HTTPS or not. If you want to have one Tomcat contact another via HTTPS, the server needs to be configured for SSL (which is supported) but then the client needs to be configured to connect using SSL (which Tomcat does not handle at all, and configuration must be done entirely separately).

Comment: Well, presumably, the webapp running within Tomcat is using Java (Axis2/JAX-WS according to the question), so configuring that client to use `https://` is more natural. Using `stunnel` would make it make a local connection to the tunnel first, which is unnecessary. It's just as easy to configure the trust store in the webapp.

Comment: Fair enough. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: Currently I am able to send the client request and receive the server response without SSL enabled. Now If I use the method suggested, does it mean that I should also modify the existing code accordingly or the current working code still holds good.

Comment: All you would have to change (once you set up `stunnel`) is the hostname and port number you use to communicate.